Content not injected in app-root when using Cypress
I started to implement end to end testing to my Angular app, but when running the tests, my app is not visible on the browser opened by Cypress. The content is not injected by the router as far as I can see.
<app-root>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <!--container-->
</app-root>

The app is running and the content is inserted properly when serving it on another tab, at the same time with the e2e testing.
Do I have to do some specific settings for the angular router to work with Cypress? Or is it something related to my Cypress config? I can share the config if it's needed, but it's a minimal config, anyway.
I found this thread, but it wasn't too helpful: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4383
Sorry, I am beginner with Cypress and e2e.
Thanks!

As mentioned, Cypress e2e does not care about the app internals. If you take a bog standard ng new app with router, Cypress runs without issue.

You will have to provide more than just three lines of code to get a solution to your problem.

@Samantha - you are right, but I am not sure what is needed here, if it's about the config or something else. I don't have a problem with a specific test case . I am having the most basic test, but the problem is that the pages of the app are not injected and I don't have access to the elements I need to target.

Since you are using e2e testing the test runner will not care about the internal router implementation - it just uses the HTML presented on the page to test.
You should inspect the devtools for (shift-ctrl-i) for errors in the Console panel or broken fetch on the Network panel.

If you are actually testing via the component testing feature, there is a hidden example here
(the Cypress docs on Angular are not very comprehensive)
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should redirect to welcome screen when creds are correct', () => {
    cy.mount(AppComponent);
    cy.contains('Username').find('input').type('testuser');
    cy.contains('Password').find('input').type('testPassword');
    cy.intercept('POST', '/auth', {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: {
        status: 200,
        message: 'Authenticated',
      },
    });
    cy.get('button').contains('Login').contains('Login').click();
    cy.contains('Welcome testuser');
  });

  it('should show error message when creds are incorrect', () => {
    cy.mount(AppComponent);
    cy.contains('Username').find('input').type('baduser');
    cy.contains('Password').find('input').type('badpassword');
    cy.intercept('POST', '/auth', {
      statusCode: 401,
      body: {
        status: 401,
        message: 'Bad username or password',
      },
    });
    cy.get('button').contains('Login').click();
    cy.contains('Bad username or password');
  });
});

Using TestBed
IMO the non-cypress TestBed spec in the same repo is much better (but you can run it in the cypress runner)
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


Thanks for your reply! I am not using the component testing feature. I am trying to define some basic/starting e2e tests. I understand what you said about the fact that it doesn't matter what the Angular router does, but only the HTML file. But the problem is that the generated HTML doesn't contain the actual page, so either it's a problem with how Cypress works with the Angular router, or something else.
